# VBA : How to run other subroutines with the choosen values from ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba

I have a ComboBox (created with Active X) with values like :

[image]

I would like to chose the value and run other subroutines with the last number from the chosen value (it is displayed in E18) :
[image]

I don't know how to proceed because the ByRef doesn't seem to be working with comboBox. My code is:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Range("Partenaire_cible")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim inputString As String
        Dim stringArray As Variant
        Dim argString As String
        
        inputString = Target.Value
        stringArray = Split(inputString, " ")
        argString = Target.Offset(1, 0).Value
        GET_GROUPE_GESTION_CIBLE (argString)
        INFO_PROTO1 (argString)
        INFO_PROTO2 (argString)
        INFO_PROTO3 (argString)
        PROTO_CIBLE (argString)
        FRAIS (argString)
End If
```

The `argString = Target.Offset(1, 0).Value` is the value from E18.

All subroutines use `ByRef` like:  `Public Sub INFO_PROTO3(ByRef strQ As String)` but it doesn't work.
I don't know how to replace the `ByRef strQ` in this case.
Thank you for your help !

Code in the Sheet 1

```
    Option Explicit



    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Integer
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C6")) Is Nothing Then
    Call CLICK_BTN_INFOS_CONTRAT
    Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi 
    Commercial").Range("GET_GROUPE_GESTION_CIBLE").Value = ""
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Range("Partenaire_cible")) Is 
    Nothing 
    Then
    Dim inputString As String
    Dim stringArray As Variant
    Dim argString As String
    
    inputString = Target.Value
    stringArray = Split(inputString, " ")
    argString = Target.Offset(1, 0).Value
    GET_GROUPE_GESTION_CIBLE (argString)
    INFO_PROTO1 (argString)
    INFO_PROTO2 (argString)
    INFO_PROTO3 (argString)
    PROTO_CIBLE (argString)
    FRAIS (argString)
   End If
   End Sub
```

My code for Subroutines is like :

```
Public Sub INFO_PROTO3(ByRef strQ As String)

Dim RECSET As New ADODB.Recordset, numero_de_police
Call CONNEXION_PEGASE("xxx", "xxxx", "xxx")
numero_de_police = Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi 
 Commercial").Range("C6").Value

If Len(numero_de_police) > 0 Then
     RECSET.Open " select proto.b_perf_ctrat_gar as b_perf_ctrat_gar from 
 db_dossier sousc,db_produit prod, db_protocole proto" & _
        " where sousc.no_police = '" & numero_de_police & "'  and 
 sousc.cd_dossier = 'SOUSC' and " & _
        " sousc.lp_etat_doss not in ('ANNUL','A30','IMPAY') and 
  sousc.is_produit = prod.is_produit and prod.cd_produit||'/'||'" & strQ & "' 
 = proto.cd_protocole ", cnn_Pegase, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic
    
    With Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi 
   Commercial").Range("Calcul_Perf_Contrat_et_Orient")
        If Not RECSET.EOF Then
            .Value = RECSET.Fields("b_perf_ctrat_gar").Value
        Else
            .Value = "0"
        End If
    End With
    RECSET.Close
 End If
  Call DECONNEXION_PEGASE
End Sub
```

Comment: can you tell more about Active X component you are using? is it self made component? do you have documentation for this component?

Comment: Is your posted code part of an event? If yes, it would be good to edit your question and show us the whole code. And also show us at least one of the called function code. Otherwise, it is difficult to properly understand what is happening and why your code does not work as you want. Where in your code are you referring to the ComboBox value? Is the combo linked to "E18" cell?

Comment: Is this a code made by you, or took from somebody else? Why do you need that `ByRef` argument? `ByRef` is used only if you intend to modify the argument itself inside the called function/sub. Is this what you want?

Comment: This code is not concerned with comboboxes, only with cell values, so the fact that there is a combobox is not relevant. There is nothing that would prevent *this code* from working provided that `Target` is a single cell. It does include incorrect parentheses around `argString`, but they would not prevent you from calling the subs. They would however prevent the subs from modifying `argString`, so if the idea of your code is that each sub modifies `argString`, then that would not work.

Comment: @FaneDuru, it's my old code, before the introducing the comboBox I hade a simple list, so I clicked on the list's value and I run other subroutines with the key as last number of choosen value.

Comment: @FaneDuru I don't want modify the values. I'm asking how to "take" the chosen value from the list and put it in input of my subrotines : GET_GROUPE_GESTION_CIBLE (argString)
    INFO_PROTO1 (argString)
    INFO_PROTO2 (argString)
    INFO_PROTO3 (argString)
    PROTO_CIBLE (argString)
    FRAIS (argString)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I added the code to my main message.

Comment: Is "Partenaire_cible" a named range? If yes, is it linked to the combobox in discussion?

Comment: @FaneDuru : I would like to click on the list and run Public Sub INFO_PROTO3(with A11872 on iput)    :)

Comment: @FaneDuru I added the code

Comment: @FaneDuru I linked partenaire_cible to comboBox

Comment: @FaneDuru I used by Ref before because I worked with simple list, I just don't know how to proceed for remplacing by Ref, beacause It doesn't work now when I click on the list

Comment: Try simple deleting `ByRef` from all called functions!

Comment: @FaneDuru using just INFO_PROTO1() ?

Comment: @FaneDuru Thank you, I replaced, ti doesn't work : INFO_PROTO1(strQ As String)
 :(

Comment: @FaneDuru `strQ As String` *is* `ByRef strQ As String`.

Comment: You shouldn't have parentheses around the value you are passing unless you are using Call. By having them you are negating the effect of passing ByRef.

Comment: @Marie You still have not explained what "does not work" means. It is, however, very clearly not related to `ByRef` that you [keep bringing up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640).

Comment: @GSerg I does not work because I have no results, I hade the results before (while using the simple list, not Combobox). Thank you

Comment: @norie When I'm using the Public Sub FRAIS ByRef strQ As String it doesn't work

Comment: @GSerg: Yes, you I right! I missed their meaning... Probably, it is only a matter of parenthesis...

Comment: @FaneDuru I must write only Public Sub FRAIS ByRef strQ As String, without parenthesis ? It's in red

Comment: @Marie Like I said, this has nothing to do with the combobox. I assume that you have linked the combobox to a cell, and you are reading the combobox current value as `Target.Value`. You are then splitting it, and proceed to ignore the split result, instead taking the value of the cell immediately below the `Target`. At this point it is not even clear to me whether you have even set up the combobox to output its value in a sheet cell. If indeed so, then use the last element of your `stringArray` instead of the `Target.Offset(1, 0).Value`.

Comment: @GSerg yes, I linked my ComboBOx, when I'm making the test like: in G17 I put =E17 I have a value from my ComboBox. I'll teste your solution tomorrow, thank you very much !

Comment: @GSerg and "Partenaire cible" has value of combobox, I tested.

Comment: @GSerg When I click on the ComboBox the value from E17 (Partenaire_cible) go to E18 where I put the formula: =SI(E17="";"";STXT(E17;CHERCHE("|";SUBSTITUE(E17;"-";"|";NBCAR(E17)-NBCAR(SUBSTITUE(E17;"-";""))))+1;99))  , with this "Key", from E18, I would like to run the other Subroutines but it doesn't work any more  :)

Answer (score -1):

When calling the other subs don't use parentheses, it negates the effect of ByRef.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim inputString As String
Dim stringArray As Variant
Dim argString As String

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C6")) Is Nothing Then
        Call CLICK_BTN_INFOS_CONTRAT
        Worksheets("1 - Feuille de SuiviCommercial").Range("GET_GROUPE_GESTION_CIBLE").Value = ""
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Range("Partenaire_cible")) Is Nothing Then
        inputString = Target.Value
        stringArray = Split(inputString, " ")
        argString = Target.Offset(1, 0).Value
        GET_GROUPE_GESTION_CIBLE (argString)
        INFO_PROTO1 argString
        INFO_PROTO2 argString
        INFO_PROTO3 argString
        PROTO_CIBLE argString
        FRAIS argString
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: While that is true, it has no effect in this particular situation.

Comment: @norie Thank you !

Comment: @GSerg My code worked before, I just changed the simple list on ComboBox that I created with ActiveX tool